# Getting Post Title on URL Angular

Tags: angular

```js
getAllPosts() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paraMap: ParamMap) => {
    this.postsService.getAllPosts();
    this.postsSub = this.postsService
      .getPostsUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
        this.posts = posts;
      });
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    this.authListenerSubs = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe((isAuthenticated) => {
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="soc-fd posts_list d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="feed-item" *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <div class="feed-item__user-link--for-avatar">
      <a href="" class="user-link__link">
        <picture class="user-link__avatar">
          <span class="user-link__name"></span>
        </picture>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="feed-item__content d-flex flex-column" (click)="onPostClick(post.postId)">
```

I am using postId to get navigate to a post from a list of posts.

```
 onPostClick(postId: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/post', postId]);
 }
```

and my URL is http://localhost:4200/post/631037f93d425d3584030c84

How do I change the Id to Post Title in the URL?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and is lacking enough information to help you out with. Where does the post title come from? Where is the onPostClick method called? What models do you have and what do they look like? What do you want to do with the post title? etc.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I have added snippets of my component code and template code. Am getting the postId from the getPosts and onPostClick is called on the Post Title <div> tag